# Taylor expansion of a vector field (notation question)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Is there an index-less notation (using gradiends, Jacobians, curls, hessians, anything) to describe a second-order term in the Taylor expansion of a vector field $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Up to the linear terms, it's nicely written using the Jacobian matrix:
$$
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) \approx \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}) + D_{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0})(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0}) + O(\mathbf{x}^2)
$$

I don't know how is it better to express the quadratic part without ugly indices:
$$
O(\mathbf{x}^2)_j = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0})^TD^2f_j(\mathbf{x_0})(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0}) + O(\mathbf{x}^3)_j
$$

Comment: I answered to the case $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$, and I canceled my answer: sorry for that. If $f$ is vector valued, one just writes the Taylor expansion for each component, as you did. Have you some specific problem in mind, which would require a simplified notation?

Comment: 1) kinda, I want to derive ODE's from one of the papers, but in matrix form (time-evolution of covariance matrix). Later I'll have to consider block-matrix versions of those, so I thought if I will use index notation it can get very messy at some point. 2) I generally enjoy the elegance of the vector notation and try to stick to it when possible. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As one can see from
$$df^i=\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}dx^j+\frac12\frac{\partial^2f^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}dx^jdx^k+\cdots$$
The second order term is actually a third-order tensor and we cannot express it using matrix notation. But forget matrix, just remember it is a tensor. Then by denoting $D^2f=\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2f^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}e_i\otimes e^j\otimes e^k$, we have
$$f(x)\approx f(x_0)+Df(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)+\frac12D^2f(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)^2$$
where bullet $\cdot$ means inner product and $x^2=x\otimes x$.

Comment: That looks very slick. I'm just beginning with tensors, and am not sure whether the position of those indices somehow influences the way the dot product is performed. According to wiki, $D^2f(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0)^2$ should be a 3-d order tensor again. Why isn't it the case?

Comment: @dmytro Yes, the position of indices is important since tensors are not always symmetric. Essentially, as what I've mentioned, $D^2f$ is 3d order tensor of type (1,2). But $D^2f\cdot x^2$ is a vector and hence first order tensor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you point to some quick intro to tensors? I just need to do the same with second-order tensor fields and need to keep track of indices not to mess up the thing

Comment: @dmytro Try lectures on differential geometry by S.S. Chern